# How to handle booleans with Oracle's Managed ODP.Net

Tags: c#, odp.net

I have a legacy application that until now has worked quite nicely with Microsoft's deprecated System.Data.OracleClient driver. C# boolean values are generally represented in its Oracle database as Number(5,0). For years this has worked quite serenely.

We are now attempting to migrate to Oracle's Managed ODP.Net replacement, and Booleans are proving particularly troublesome. Having replaced the Microsoft driver with the Oracle ODP.Net nuget package, I find that write operations with sql such as "insert..   where mybooleancolumn = true" (or parameterised equivalents) throw an 'undefined datatype' exception, and reading boolean values from the database ("Select mybooleancolumn from ....") gives all sort of errors when the values are assigned to C# booleans.

How do others overcome this problem? Is there some additional mapping that needs to be done?

Answer (score 1):

In the Oracle database I'm connecting to (using Oracle's Managed ODP.NET), the boolean are represented with a NUMBER(1, 0).

Here is the correct mapping code in my web.config that allows this mapping to work correctly:

```
<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
      <edmMappings>
        <edmNumberMapping>
          <add NETType="bool" MinPrecision="1" MaxPrecision="1" DBType="Number" />
          <add NETType="byte" MinPrecision="2" MaxPrecision="2" DBType="Number" />
          <add NETType="int16" MinPrecision="3" MaxPrecision="4" DBType="Number" />
          <add NETType="int32" MinPrecision="5" MaxPrecision="9" DBType="Number" />
          <add NETType="int64" MinPrecision="10" MaxPrecision="19" DBType="Number" />
        </edmNumberMapping>
      </edmMappings>

      <settings>
       <setting name="TNS_ADMIN" value="PATH TO TNS_ADMIN" />
      </settings>
    </version>
  </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
```

The important bit is:

```
<add NETType="bool" MinPrecision="1" MaxPrecision="1" DBType="Number" />
```

If you define such a mapping it should work.

EDIT: Don't forget to refresh your edmx model (just update it with no changes) and to rebuild the application to make sure it is updated using the new mappings.

Comment: Unfortunately that has made no difference. I'm using Managed ODP.Net 12.2.1100

Comment: @NeilHaughton did you specify the mapping with the same value (5, 0) as used in your database and not my value ?

Comment: @NeilHaughton have you tried regenerating the EDMX file? If not it's probably still using the old values it generated the first time around.

Comment: EDMX is an Entity Framework thing, isn't it? I'm not using EF, just plain ADO.Net.

Comment: Giles, the table columns in question are Number(1,0), and I'm using your xml as written above. I just copied your edmMappings section into my app.config. Hold the horses - isn't the edmMappings an EF thing? How do I achieve the same if I am not using EF (this is a legacy application)?

Comment: @NeilHaughton indeed, it's for EF. I've always either used EF or Dapper, unless when I'm calling a stored proc directly (which is rare). Maybe if you could post a bit of code where you are getting an error?

Comment: This is fairly typical (stripped down somewhat)::             using (IDbCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = cn;
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT LockedBy FROM Screen WHERE Name = 'About' AND IsLocked = True AND AuditFlag = False";
                return cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            }

Comment: where IsLocked and AuditFlag are NUMBER(1,0) or NUMBER(5,0)columns. Works perfectly with Sql Server or Oracle with the Microsoft System.Data.OracleClient data provider.

Answer (score 1):

I made it work by adding mapping in config:

```
    <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
        <version number="*">
            <edmMappings>
                <edmMapping dataType="number">
                    <add name="bool" precision="1"/>
                </edmMapping>
            </edmMappings>
        </version>
    </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
```

And setting OracleCommand's [UseEdmMapping](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/odpnt/CommandUseEdmMapping.html#GUID-97B95E1F-D9E8-4F16-B7E9-29AEE24A6038) to true.
Something like this:

```
string oradb = "Data Source=ORCL;User Id=hr;Password=hr;";
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb);
conn.Open(); 
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
cmd.UseEdmMapping = true; // # THIS IS WHAT I HAD TO SET TO TRUE #
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = "select department_name from departments where department_id = 10";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; 
OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
dr.Read();
label1.Text = dr.GetString(0);
conn.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it set the OracleParameter's OracleDbType to Int32 but set it's Value to a Boolean.  e.g.

```
var param = new OracleParameter("mybooleancolumn", OracleDbType.Int32);
param.Value = true;
```